# Calculate eigen value in python as same way(order) in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

This is the Matlab code which is returning eigenvector in V and eigenvalue in D. Consider C is 9*9 matrix then V is 9*9 matrix and D is 9*9 diagonal. matrix.

```
[V,D] = eig(C);
```

I want the same thing in Python and in the same order as Matlab. I am using this code:

```
[V1, D] = np.linalg.eig(C)    
V = np.zeros((9,9))

for i in range(9):
    V[i][i] = V1[i]
```

(consider V to be in the for loop)

This code is giving me eigenvalue in V1 and eigenvector in D. I changed V1 to V to get a diagonal 9*9 matrix.

But the problem is that I want the eigenvalue and vector in the same order as Matlab which I am not getting in the python. Please help me in getting the values in the same order as Matlab.

See the link below for the difference in values between Matlab and python.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zjhbKH0q_XXbBziZhfpL1-qS3B5oDuMb

Comment: Please refrain from asking the exact same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51250606/7328782

Comment: I’m glad you got a more explicit answer this time. My comment to “sort the eigenvalues” wasn’t clear enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

Matlab will output the eigenvalues to the diagonal elements of the D matrix in ascending order (i.e. lowest eigenvalue is D(1,1) and the largest one is D(9,9)).

Python doesn't follow this convention and the outputs (eigenvalues and eigenvectors) must be sorted with something like;

```
ind = np.argsort(V1);
V1 = V1[ind];
D = D[:,ind];
```