# trying to return same eigen values and vectors results from numpy linalg eig as matlab eig does

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to convert MATLABs eig function into python. I am trying to return the same results as MATLABs eig does in python, and I am using numpy.linalg.eig to try and do this, but it won't return the same values & vectors. I am currently using matlab engine to call the matlab code from jupyter notebooks.

 This is my jupyter notebooks code:

```
    L_by_L_conj_trans = np.matmul(L, L_transpose_conjugate)
    L_by_L_matlab = matlab.double(L_by_L_conj_trans.tolist())
    
    print("\nTHE MATRIX:\n")
    print(L_by_L_conj_trans)
    
    from numpy.linalg import eig
    values, vectors = eig(L_by_L_conj_trans)
    
    e_values_and_e_vectors = eng.eig(L_by_L_matlab, nargout=2)
    e_values = eng.diag(e_values_and_e_vectors[1])
    e_vectors = e_values_and_e_vectors[0]
    temp_e_values = eng.diag(e_values_and_e_vectors[1])
    
    
    print("\nE VECTOR FOR MATLAB ENG:")
    print(np.around(e_vectors, decimals = 4))
    print("\n E VECTOR FOR NUMPY.EIG:")
    print(np.around(vectors, decimals = 4))
    
    print("\n\nE VALUES FOR MATLAB ENG:")
    print(np.around(temp_e_values, decimals = 4))
    print("\nE VALUES FOR NUMPY.EIG:")
    print(np.around(values, decimals = 4))
```

these are the outputs.

```
THE MATRIX:

[[ 1672.2368  1304.6274   -66.8953  -521.5597  -585.8664  -790.4093
   -408.2504  -885.7773  -273.2319  1314.0962   754.2331  1005.8871
    393.6987   566.7153   289.5906   766.5018    59.1187  1305.7717
   1085.8418  1061.5296  -981.1831 -1108.7448 -1035.0104  -874.2488
  -1152.0593  -587.4416  -925.0897 -1058.5672   110.7806  -436.2941]
 [ 1304.6274  1638.5357  -508.4575   -32.5526  -772.4504  -559.9273
   -929.1771  -360.9589  -239.6309   768.5568  1327.8857   406.7315
    965.1604   312.0877   603.4783    63.0486   770.1663  1000.8222
   1315.5369  1080.7256 -1121.3858 -1013.4135 -1056.66   -1160.3771
   -864.6467  -959.508   -598.2808 -1047.6508  -435.0306   102.7449]
 [  -66.8953  -508.4575  1264.7399  -415.9097   954.5501    84.8193
   1082.8333  -970.3041   550.9171   559.8939  -579.5      182.3674
   -879.7133   765.624    -32.4137   915.6522  -919.4347  -259.3591
   -578.1347   122.128    -75.245   -568.1983  -336.3324   900.2402
   -327.6103   340.3344  -979.9465   395.3746   486.6892 -1108.709 ]
 [ -521.5597   -32.5526  -415.9097  1255.2618    69.2946   935.0607
   -889.8419   977.6712   542.3181  -561.3287   553.433   -875.0436
    246.4148   -46.6133   751.6661  -908.667    907.7992  -571.706
   -269.069    110.9489  -577.549    -66.6523  -332.4622  -383.3139
    891.2615  -970.9352   315.0077   375.1399 -1074.2033   566.13  ]
 [ -585.8664  -772.4504   954.5501    69.2946  1116.7921   620.8967
    736.708   -423.9882   769.1498   -60.1744  -605.2978  -394.0691
   -864.2684   475.785     75.9278   200.7536  -689.2869  -658.3288
   -818.0084  -147.6736   118.1881  -148.1829   -20.6568  1019.1842
    338.4077   162.0875  -553.5004   906.8372   -20.187   -802.6226]
 [ -790.4093  -559.9273    84.8193   935.0607   620.8967  1103.3559
   -292.8921   585.3663   766.5463  -582.738    -79.4964  -877.3192
   -351.2562    73.8414   464.7332  -668.9234   178.7148  -796.5485
   -685.1508  -153.1674  -158.6839   134.5685   -15.6088   298.8065
   1031.2407  -527.1156   128.1918   899.4578  -786.0648    19.7015]
 [ -408.2504  -929.1771  1082.8333  -889.8419   736.708   -292.8921
   1772.2627  -954.2527   -29.5541   115.3221 -1143.484    390.5774
   -978.9792   117.1943  -745.1069   957.7335 -1266.6559  -308.4591
   -696.3893  -569.8382   887.3478    94.3312   466.4671  1329.8271
   -358.8517  1463.1915  -560.0082   409.2915  1312.3746 -1003.7211]
 [ -885.7773  -360.9589  -970.3041   977.6712  -423.9882   585.3663
   -954.2527  1818.3831  -164.121  -1151.2921   119.3964  -890.1043
    529.1385  -836.7234     9.2113 -1263.3481   987.7814  -619.946
   -262.0244  -627.2201   149.6067   966.6453   540.8085  -457.2442
   1188.2508  -504.024   1575.8039   279.5336  -880.6917  1524.4232]
 [ -273.2319  -239.6309   550.9171   542.3181   769.1498   766.5463
    -29.5541  -164.121    918.228     86.9774    66.3333  -499.7766
   -462.5373   638.2798   639.4247   -74.0544   -89.1164  -493.4879
   -500.8334   347.2257  -511.739   -498.1427  -509.3759   300.7608
    342.898   -559.5687  -580.7794   577.2742  -541.9846  -518.3992]
 [ 1314.0962   768.5568   559.8939  -561.3287   -60.1744  -582.738
    115.3221 -1151.2921    86.9774  1497.8875   365.6539   944.721
   -139.689    956.6734   311.327   1179.9674  -358.767    841.9698
    489.3426  1021.8401  -922.0732 -1217.3966 -1070.9645  -390.6421
  -1094.2483  -395.6316 -1224.1635  -730.2345   318.8729  -873.7583]
 [  754.2331  1327.8857  -579.5      553.433   -605.2978   -79.4964
  -1143.484    119.3964    66.3333   365.6539  1487.3986  -115.7606
    983.3692   278.7341   934.4928  -358.5228  1175.5383   453.0208
    885.7007   994.8795 -1200.2441  -912.7615 -1054.4111 -1132.7298
   -392.9712 -1217.3632  -381.4163  -745.8815  -838.4371   378.208 ]
 [ 1005.8871   406.7315   182.3674  -875.0436  -394.0691  -877.3192
    390.5774  -890.1043  -499.7766   944.721   -115.7606  1388.235
    -28.9094   187.0458  -377.0809  1125.4583  -493.102   1035.0343
    542.4916   248.9978  -202.7081  -549.4141  -377.0669  -271.0633
  -1007.1828   366.4488  -609.8339  -767.8338  1007.238   -494.9654]
 [  393.6987   965.1604  -879.7133   246.4148  -864.2684  -351.2562
   -978.9792   529.1385  -462.5373  -139.689    983.3692   -28.9094
   1351.1613  -372.4145   222.5584  -530.0618  1167.9523   470.4503
    996.3646   248.9961  -561.3745  -224.2025  -390.1503 -1012.3292
   -263.3968  -668.4316   376.4798  -747.0418  -496.7554  1019.7668]
 [  566.7153   312.0877   765.624    -46.6133   475.785     73.8414
    117.1943  -836.7234   638.2798   956.6734   278.7341   187.0458
   -372.4145  1058.6183   606.9181   676.3046  -280.1271   123.5983
    -44.9316   875.7814  -848.958  -1048.8959  -953.8193    -7.9936
   -510.2376  -544.6276 -1112.8701  -110.533   -134.0033  -860.4531]
 [  289.5906   603.4783   -32.4137   751.6661    75.9278   464.7332
   -745.1069     9.2113   639.4247   311.327    934.4928  -377.0809
    222.5584   606.9181  1053.8515  -253.7967   648.956    -61.7748
    139.492    874.9251 -1056.5503  -853.0907  -957.8459  -550.591
      6.1055 -1100.1048  -575.3495  -117.2291  -848.0141  -103.71  ]
 [  766.5018    63.0486   915.6522  -908.667    200.7536  -668.9234
    957.7335 -1263.3481   -74.0544  1179.9674  -358.5228  1125.4583
   -530.0618   676.3046  -253.7967  1538.1741  -875.7897   558.2818
     51.2102   358.2182  -267.905   -821.8163  -558.7778   249.1165
  -1024.2857   454.2618 -1082.7859  -449.29    1079.0482 -1035.7061]
 [   59.1187   770.1663  -919.4347   907.7992  -689.2869   178.7148
  -1266.6559   987.7814   -89.1164  -358.767   1175.5383  -493.102
   1167.9523  -280.1271   648.956   -875.7897  1533.8702    31.1288
    566.0777   329.5361  -810.013   -264.7564  -545.2707 -1059.5201
    215.8949 -1084.2595   457.1963  -468.0846  -977.8071  1152.2603]
 [ 1305.7717  1000.8222  -259.3591  -571.706   -658.3288  -796.5485
   -308.4591  -619.946   -493.4879   841.9698   453.0208  1035.0343
    470.4503   123.5983   -61.7748   558.2818    31.1288  1345.0612
   1096.2847   544.6469  -562.8242  -662.655   -599.8857  -728.5503
   -935.051   -251.9314  -506.8401  -920.4689   294.3521  -162.6059]
 [ 1085.8418  1315.5369  -578.1347  -269.069   -818.0084  -685.1508
   -696.3893  -262.0244  -500.8334   489.3426   885.7007   542.4916
    996.3646   -44.9316   139.492     51.2102   566.0777  1096.2847
   1394.7885   582.3308  -677.5779  -612.862   -631.079   -957.5032
   -782.1503  -534.579   -271.883   -957.3816  -130.2972   264.3925]
 [ 1061.5296  1080.7256   122.128    110.9489  -147.6736  -153.1674
   -569.8382  -627.2201   347.2257  1021.8401   994.8795   248.9978
    248.9961   875.7814   874.9251   358.2182   329.5361   544.6469
    582.3308  1261.4653 -1208.7132 -1214.5693 -1209.1391  -720.3987
   -701.0027  -983.0365  -999.2312  -622.8998  -451.8526  -455.4328]
 [ -981.1831 -1121.3858   -75.245   -577.549    118.1881  -158.6839
    887.3478   149.6067  -511.739   -922.0732 -1200.2441  -202.7081
   -561.3745  -848.958  -1056.5503  -267.905   -810.013   -562.8242
   -677.5779 -1208.7132  1949.046   1563.2136  1785.1945   988.0245
    420.9193  1630.2179   885.1134   586.3745   752.4566    29.0243]
 [-1108.7448 -1013.4135  -568.1983   -66.6523  -148.1829   134.5685
     94.3312   966.6453  -498.1427 -1217.3966  -912.7615  -549.4141
   -224.2025 -1048.8959  -853.0907  -821.8163  -264.7564  -662.655
   -612.862  -1214.5693  1563.2136  1948.3819  1789.3347   456.9566
    950.6646   862.9705  1626.6346   601.1836    64.697    726.1729]
 [-1035.0104 -1056.66    -336.3324  -332.4622   -20.6568   -15.6088
    466.4671   540.8085  -509.3759 -1070.9645 -1054.4111  -377.0669
   -390.1503  -953.8193  -957.8459  -558.7778  -545.2707  -599.8857
   -631.079  -1209.1391  1785.1945  1789.3347  1834.4847   717.0277
    684.8884  1231.5105  1251.0325   601.1818   387.9073   364.679 ]
 [ -874.2488 -1160.3771   900.2402  -383.3139  1019.1842   298.8065
   1329.8271  -457.2442   300.7608  -390.6421 -1132.7298  -271.0633
  -1012.3292    -7.9936  -550.591    249.1165 -1059.5201  -728.5503
   -957.5032  -720.3987   988.0245   456.9566   717.0277  1504.9006
    324.7611  1060.6166  -219.9223   997.901    557.4361  -779.1317]
 [-1152.0593  -864.6467  -327.6103   891.2615   338.4077  1031.2407
   -358.8517  1188.2508   342.898  -1094.2483  -392.9712 -1007.1828
   -263.3968  -510.2376     6.1055 -1024.2857   215.8949  -935.051
   -782.1503  -701.0027   420.9193   950.6646   684.8884   324.7611
   1464.3562  -217.0687   958.3422  1009.1323  -740.089    543.7288]
 [ -587.4416  -959.508    340.3344  -970.9352   162.0875  -527.1156
   1463.1915  -504.024   -559.5687  -395.6316 -1217.3632   366.4488
   -668.4316  -544.6276 -1100.1048   454.2618 -1084.2595  -251.9314
   -534.579   -983.0365  1630.2179   862.9705  1231.5105  1060.6166
   -217.0687  2028.4758   208.8387   231.2736  1498.3925  -432.993 ]
 [ -925.0897  -598.2808  -979.9465   315.0077  -553.5004   128.1918
   -560.0082  1575.8039  -580.7794 -1224.1635  -381.4163  -609.8339
    376.4798 -1112.8701  -575.3495 -1082.7859   457.1963  -506.8401
   -271.883   -999.2312   885.1134  1626.6346  1251.0325  -219.9223
    958.3422   208.8387  2032.4677   198.9546  -342.8214  1510.6592]
 [-1058.5672 -1047.6508   395.3746   375.1399   906.8372   899.4578
    409.2915   279.5336   577.2742  -730.2345  -745.8815  -767.8338
   -747.0418  -110.533   -117.2291  -449.29    -468.0846  -920.4689
   -957.3816  -622.8998   586.3745   601.1836   601.1818   997.901
   1009.1323   231.2736   198.9546  1239.2189  -282.8466  -282.1859]
 [  110.7806  -435.0306   486.6892 -1074.2033   -20.187   -786.0648
   1312.3746  -880.6917  -541.9846   318.8729  -838.4371  1007.238
   -496.7554  -134.0033  -848.0141  1079.0482  -977.8071   294.3521
   -130.2972  -451.8526   752.4566    64.697    387.9073   557.4361
   -740.089   1498.3925  -342.8214  -282.8466  1740.6614  -629.8207]
 [ -436.2941   102.7449 -1108.709    566.13    -802.6226    19.7015
  -1003.7211  1524.4232  -518.3992  -873.7583   378.208   -494.9654
   1019.7668  -860.4531  -103.71   -1035.7061  1152.2603  -162.6059
    264.3925  -455.4328    29.0243   726.1729   364.679   -779.1317
    543.7288  -432.993   1510.6592  -282.1859  -629.8207  1778.6173]]

E VECTOR FOR MATLAB ENG:
[[-0.1826  0.0415  0.0073 -0.0526 -0.2615  0.1539 -0.1883  0.0069 -0.3068
   0.1423 -0.0983 -0.1769  0.2225  0.003   0.0107  0.3313 -0.1421 -0.3593
  -0.1252 -0.0403  0.2294  0.1265  0.3098  0.0134 -0.0568 -0.2024 -0.2167
   0.1255 -0.0792 -0.2744]
 [-0.1826  0.0664  0.0187  0.0602  0.392   0.0876 -0.1551 -0.226   0.2537
  -0.1418  0.0705  0.1744  0.2198 -0.1101  0.0564  0.2404 -0.1873  0.297
  -0.1163  0.0108 -0.3147  0.0443  0.2449 -0.0503 -0.0203  0.194  -0.2205
   0.1039  0.0763 -0.2771]
 [-0.1826 -0.2298 -0.0438  0.3856  0.0433  0.1023  0.0927  0.0579 -0.1799
   0.2621  0.3516 -0.0832  0.0864 -0.2361  0.1442 -0.0022 -0.2974  0.0129
   0.3003  0.0619 -0.0843  0.0183 -0.0568 -0.3352  0.0361 -0.0046  0.1397
  -0.2018 -0.2368  0.0111]
 [-0.1826 -0.21   -0.0656 -0.3483 -0.0269  0.1421  0.0785 -0.1322  0.2117
   0.1056  0.4019  0.0094  0.1098  0.2667 -0.0352  0.2498  0.08   -0.0348
   0.3517  0.0177  0.096   0.1098  0.0089  0.3478 -0.0279  0.0051  0.1206
  -0.2186  0.2257  0.0038]
 [-0.1826  0.4032  0.0412 -0.4674  0.1237 -0.2957  0.2258  0.0724 -0.0078
   0.1753 -0.0743 -0.0162  0.0692  0.1282  0.158   0.0925 -0.3037  0.0316
  -0.107   0.1154  0.0583 -0.157  -0.0754 -0.2327 -0.1461  0.0454 -0.0155
  -0.283  -0.1248  0.0918]
 [-0.1826  0.4003  0.0386  0.4908 -0.2827 -0.1577  0.1636  0.0332  0.1385
  -0.1958  0.0572  0.0422  0.0606 -0.1543  0.0412  0.2903  0.1485 -0.0444
  -0.0071 -0.1521 -0.027  -0.1069 -0.0463  0.2252 -0.1841 -0.0617 -0.0277
  -0.2917  0.1086  0.0885]
 [-0.1826  0.0607 -0.0321 -0.1778  0.0739  0.1155  0.2033  0.1267 -0.091
  -0.3598 -0.157   0.1075  0.1933 -0.2063 -0.1923  0.0082  0.317  -0.2151
   0.2077  0.181  -0.1113  0.1753  0.2834 -0.1042 -0.0275  0.2128  0.226
  -0.0027 -0.3013  0.1357]
 [-0.1826  0.0525 -0.0089  0.1494 -0.0622  0.1396  0.1612  0.037   0.1508
   0.0959 -0.4364 -0.1293  0.1959  0.157  -0.0424 -0.2856 -0.2631  0.2637
   0.1572 -0.0701  0.0453  0.1301  0.3169  0.0033 -0.0069 -0.2062  0.2483
   0.0238  0.3107  0.1273]
 [-0.1826 -0.5533 -0.0399 -0.0124  0.0307 -0.1319 -0.2158  0.0559  0.0263
  -0.2146 -0.4519  0.0466  0.1553 -0.0314  0.0431  0.1466 -0.0286 -0.0071
   0.0332 -0.0001  0.0752 -0.3907 -0.1571  0.0205  0.0181 -0.0099 -0.0396
  -0.3187 -0.0091 -0.0121]
 [-0.1826 -0.077  -0.025   0.101   0.3459 -0.0993  0.168   0.4549  0.2062
  -0.0851  0.0458  0.0999 -0.1458  0.2768  0.0957  0.0327  0.1237 -0.0964
  -0.0925 -0.3301  0.1159  0.2269  0.0149 -0.0722  0.2014 -0.2797 -0.027
  -0.0127 -0.1762 -0.2282]
 [-0.1826 -0.094  -0.0395 -0.1248 -0.4195  0.0264  0.0411  0.4529  0.1518
   0.0228 -0.0234 -0.0753 -0.209  -0.1895  0.228  -0.0478 -0.0548  0.1072
  -0.1489  0.3034 -0.1782  0.1749 -0.0165  0.0901  0.1657  0.2858 -0.0478
  -0.0224  0.1693 -0.2313]
 [-0.1826 -0.0027 -0.0019  0.0172 -0.0322  0.0756  0.0458  0.0465 -0.1913
  -0.0468  0.1034  0.2284  0.3941  0.0596  0.131  -0.1675  0.1238  0.3103
  -0.2141  0.2923  0.0862  0.0199 -0.3367  0.2372 -0.1922 -0.2841  0.1374
   0.2085 -0.1837 -0.1247]
 [-0.1826  0.0013 -0.0048 -0.0211  0.0412  0.0844  0.0448 -0.0889  0.2033
   0.1457 -0.0428 -0.2958  0.3212 -0.0615  0.0944 -0.1528  0.2349 -0.2912
  -0.1317 -0.3078 -0.0238 -0.0012 -0.3759 -0.2338 -0.1354  0.2965  0.1282
   0.1723  0.1978 -0.1276]
 [-0.1826  0.2821  0.028  -0.1657 -0.2474  0.3454 -0.2994 -0.0994  0.091
  -0.3156  0.1565  0.1149 -0.0292  0.0254 -0.02   -0.369  -0.101  -0.0073
   0.099  -0.1975  0.0544 -0.1913 -0.074  -0.1488  0.2771 -0.1064 -0.0276
  -0.2126 -0.1195 -0.1438]
 [-0.1826  0.2809  0.0487  0.146   0.3831  0.1877 -0.1693  0.1026 -0.2139
   0.3592 -0.1486 -0.1412 -0.0952  0.013  -0.1751 -0.0506  0.3049  0.025
   0.0758  0.2452  0.0334 -0.1635 -0.0477  0.2111  0.2378  0.097  -0.0445
  -0.223   0.0999 -0.1478]
 [-0.1826  0.0463  0.042  -0.1197 -0.1352 -0.1017 -0.1287 -0.3545  0.068
   0.1572 -0.2818 -0.1011 -0.3011 -0.1252  0.0106  0.2613  0.1462  0.2234
   0.1172 -0.1155 -0.2129  0.2866 -0.2135 -0.0314  0.0769 -0.2203  0.2542
   0.0368 -0.2837 -0.1029]
 [-0.1826  0.0516  0.0526  0.1474  0.1327 -0.1646 -0.0516 -0.2167 -0.3428
  -0.3161 -0.0563  0.1708 -0.2099  0.1618  0.1133 -0.0227 -0.2815 -0.2255
   0.0349  0.1019  0.1768  0.3071 -0.1927  0.0413  0.0461  0.237   0.2351
   0.0153  0.2829 -0.1091]
 [-0.1826 -0.0054 -0.0047  0.01    0.1377 -0.0715  0.048  -0.0957  0.3414
  -0.0532 -0.0059 -0.1057 -0.3144 -0.2686 -0.0041 -0.221  -0.0577 -0.1716
   0.2666  0.2763  0.2867 -0.1384  0.0313  0.0602 -0.3899 -0.1726 -0.1627
   0.2106 -0.0576 -0.1961]
 [-0.1826 -0.0189 -0.0079 -0.0087 -0.1718 -0.0551  0.0572  0.157  -0.3294
   0.0212 -0.0148  0.1271 -0.1656  0.3304 -0.1398 -0.013   0.1142  0.2066
   0.3478 -0.2289 -0.2363 -0.2101  0.0098 -0.1472 -0.3523  0.167  -0.181
   0.2064  0.0577 -0.2062]
 [-0.1826 -0.1742 -0.0162  0.0115 -0.1346 -0.3728  0.4262 -0.3889 -0.1039
   0.0546  0.094  -0.0231  0.0669 -0.0372 -0.2495 -0.2713  0.1107  0.0141
  -0.1875 -0.0007 -0.0085 -0.0616  0.1824  0.0257  0.3114 -0.005  -0.1628
  -0.108  -0.0089 -0.2459]
 [-0.1826  0.066  -0.4506 -0.0345  0.0645 -0.0675 -0.0152  0.0312 -0.1238
  -0.209   0.0626 -0.379   0.0241 -0.0979 -0.0189  0.0637 -0.0294  0.3407
   0.086  -0.1459  0.3142  0.0997 -0.1168  0.0836  0.1665  0.1645 -0.2771
   0.1811 -0.0787  0.2854]
 [-0.1826  0.0645 -0.444   0.0527 -0.0571 -0.037  -0.049  -0.042   0.1188
   0.2063 -0.1059  0.3843  0.0501  0.078  -0.065  -0.0238 -0.0492 -0.3341
   0.0784  0.1663 -0.2864  0.0514 -0.1842 -0.0601  0.1737 -0.1731 -0.2758
   0.1681  0.0959  0.2847]
 [-0.1826 -0.0752  0.7262 -0.0182 -0.0167  0.0614  0.104   0.0793  0.0449
  -0.0225 -0.0055 -0.0052  0.0619 -0.0391 -0.2336  0.0723 -0.1221  0.0064
   0.0932  0.0171  0.0181  0.1071 -0.2462  0.0084  0.173  -0.0072 -0.3238
   0.1777  0.0096  0.2857]
 [-0.1826 -0.0669  0.0715  0.2113 -0.1449 -0.188  -0.4102 -0.0589  0.2205
   0.0754  0.1064 -0.0559 -0.0021  0.3868 -0.1107 -0.1157  0.1888  0.0703
  -0.1772  0.2327  0.152   0.2104  0.1637 -0.2276 -0.1819  0.1982 -0.0372
  -0.1326 -0.1884  0.2035]
 [-0.1826 -0.0649  0.0767 -0.2001  0.1511 -0.2671 -0.327   0.1245 -0.2238
   0.0398  0.1504 -0.0176  0.0083 -0.3232  0.0502 -0.3163  0.0378 -0.0481
  -0.0573 -0.2632 -0.249   0.2023  0.1343  0.1924 -0.2218 -0.1931 -0.05
  -0.1619  0.1764  0.1944]
 [-0.1826 -0.0274  0.1203  0.0199 -0.0365  0.0318  0.014  -0.1095  0.0121
   0.274  -0.0638  0.3346 -0.0926 -0.0528  0.462  -0.0718  0.062  -0.0205
   0.0045 -0.2381  0.2066 -0.1993  0.2468  0.2573  0.1213  0.3009  0.0621
   0.2078 -0.2198  0.2102]
 [-0.1826 -0.027   0.1035 -0.0199  0.0456  0.0063  0.0212 -0.0979 -0.1085
  -0.2236  0.1515 -0.2916 -0.119   0.1516  0.3995  0.1133  0.2512 -0.0328
  -0.053   0.2226 -0.1899 -0.2828  0.1717 -0.2264  0.1649 -0.2863  0.0725
   0.1969  0.235   0.2038]
 [-0.1826 -0.1678 -0.0942 -0.0085  0.0645  0.54    0.2705 -0.1564 -0.1014
  -0.0172 -0.0602  0.0289 -0.3534  0.013  -0.0568  0.0025 -0.0109  0.0174
  -0.4255 -0.0675 -0.0311  0.0703 -0.0372 -0.0224 -0.2921 -0.0087 -0.145
  -0.233  -0.0057  0.1956]
 [-0.1826 -0.0081 -0.0458  0.0534  0.0304 -0.0422 -0.0607  0.0931  0.0726
  -0.0514  0.1137 -0.2598 -0.0851  0.168  -0.31    0.0073 -0.347  -0.1763
  -0.2066 -0.0384 -0.3057 -0.2793  0.0058  0.3599  0.0139  0.0776  0.3237
   0.2128 -0.2653  0.0571]
 [-0.1826 -0.0146 -0.0503 -0.0767 -0.031  -0.0478 -0.0957  0.1351  0.0127
   0.1154  0.1613  0.288  -0.1171 -0.2863 -0.3847  0.2188  0.0323  0.1378
  -0.2036 -0.0483  0.3107 -0.1788  0.0523 -0.2851  0.0511 -0.0606  0.3345
   0.1752  0.2932  0.0486]]

 E VECTOR FOR NUMPY.EIG:
[[ 0.2744  0.0792 -0.1255 -0.2167  0.2024 -0.0568 -0.0134 -0.3098 -0.1265
  -0.2294  0.0403 -0.1252  0.3593 -0.1421  0.3313  0.0107  0.003  -0.2225
   0.1769 -0.1826 -0.0983  0.1423 -0.0415 -0.0073  0.0526  0.2615 -0.1539
   0.1883 -0.3068 -0.0069]
 [ 0.2771 -0.0763 -0.1039 -0.2205 -0.194  -0.0203  0.0503 -0.2449 -0.0443
   0.3147 -0.0108 -0.1163 -0.297  -0.1873  0.2404  0.0564 -0.1101 -0.2198
  -0.1744 -0.1826  0.0705 -0.1418 -0.0664 -0.0187 -0.0602 -0.392  -0.0876
   0.1551  0.2537  0.226 ]
 [-0.0111  0.2368  0.2018  0.1397  0.0046  0.0361  0.3352  0.0568 -0.0183
   0.0843 -0.0619  0.3003 -0.0129 -0.2974 -0.0022  0.1442 -0.2361 -0.0864
   0.0832 -0.1826  0.3516  0.2621  0.2298  0.0438 -0.3856 -0.0433 -0.1023
  -0.0927 -0.1799 -0.0579]
 [-0.0038 -0.2257  0.2186  0.1206 -0.0051 -0.0279 -0.3478 -0.0089 -0.1098
  -0.096  -0.0177  0.3517  0.0348  0.08    0.2498 -0.0352  0.2667 -0.1098
  -0.0094 -0.1826  0.4019  0.1056  0.21    0.0656  0.3483  0.0269 -0.1421
  -0.0785  0.2117  0.1322]
 [-0.0918  0.1248  0.283  -0.0155 -0.0454 -0.1461  0.2327  0.0754  0.157
  -0.0583 -0.1154 -0.107  -0.0316 -0.3037  0.0925  0.158   0.1282 -0.0692
   0.0162 -0.1826 -0.0743  0.1753 -0.4032 -0.0412  0.4674 -0.1237  0.2957
  -0.2258 -0.0078 -0.0724]
 [-0.0885 -0.1086  0.2917 -0.0277  0.0617 -0.1841 -0.2252  0.0463  0.1069
   0.027   0.1521 -0.0071  0.0444  0.1485  0.2903  0.0412 -0.1543 -0.0606
  -0.0422 -0.1826  0.0572 -0.1958 -0.4003 -0.0386 -0.4908  0.2827  0.1577
  -0.1636  0.1385 -0.0332]
 [-0.1357  0.3013  0.0027  0.226  -0.2128 -0.0275  0.1042 -0.2834 -0.1753
   0.1113 -0.181   0.2077  0.2151  0.317   0.0082 -0.1923 -0.2063 -0.1933
  -0.1075 -0.1826 -0.157  -0.3598 -0.0607  0.0321  0.1778 -0.0739 -0.1155
  -0.2033 -0.091  -0.1267]
 [-0.1273 -0.3107 -0.0238  0.2483  0.2062 -0.0069 -0.0033 -0.3169 -0.1301
  -0.0453  0.0701  0.1572 -0.2637 -0.2631 -0.2856 -0.0424  0.157  -0.1959
   0.1293 -0.1826 -0.4364  0.0959 -0.0525  0.0089 -0.1494  0.0622 -0.1396
  -0.1612  0.1508 -0.037 ]
 [ 0.0121  0.0091  0.3187 -0.0396  0.0099  0.0181 -0.0205  0.1571  0.3907
  -0.0752  0.0001  0.0332  0.0071 -0.0286  0.1466  0.0431 -0.0314 -0.1553
  -0.0466 -0.1826 -0.4519 -0.2146  0.5533  0.0399  0.0124 -0.0307  0.1319
   0.2158  0.0263 -0.0559]
 [ 0.2282  0.1762  0.0127 -0.027   0.2797  0.2014  0.0722 -0.0149 -0.2269
  -0.1159  0.3301 -0.0925  0.0964  0.1237  0.0327  0.0957  0.2768  0.1458
  -0.0999 -0.1826  0.0458 -0.0851  0.077   0.025  -0.101  -0.3459  0.0993
  -0.168   0.2062 -0.4549]
 [ 0.2313 -0.1693  0.0224 -0.0478 -0.2858  0.1657 -0.0901  0.0165 -0.1749
   0.1782 -0.3034 -0.1489 -0.1072 -0.0548 -0.0478  0.228  -0.1895  0.209
   0.0753 -0.1826 -0.0234  0.0228  0.094   0.0395  0.1248  0.4195 -0.0264
  -0.0411  0.1518 -0.4529]
 [ 0.1247  0.1837 -0.2085  0.1374  0.2841 -0.1922 -0.2372  0.3367 -0.0199
  -0.0862 -0.2923 -0.2141 -0.3103  0.1238 -0.1675  0.131   0.0596 -0.3941
  -0.2284 -0.1826  0.1034 -0.0468  0.0027  0.0019 -0.0172  0.0322 -0.0756
  -0.0458 -0.1913 -0.0465]
 [ 0.1276 -0.1978 -0.1723  0.1282 -0.2965 -0.1354  0.2338  0.3759  0.0012
   0.0238  0.3078 -0.1317  0.2912  0.2349 -0.1528  0.0944 -0.0615 -0.3212
   0.2958 -0.1826 -0.0428  0.1457 -0.0013  0.0048  0.0211 -0.0412 -0.0844
  -0.0448  0.2033  0.0889]
 [ 0.1438  0.1195  0.2126 -0.0276  0.1064  0.2771  0.1488  0.074   0.1913
  -0.0544  0.1975  0.099   0.0073 -0.101  -0.369  -0.02    0.0254  0.0292
  -0.1149 -0.1826  0.1565 -0.3156 -0.2821 -0.028   0.1657  0.2474 -0.3454
   0.2994  0.091   0.0994]
 [ 0.1478 -0.0999  0.223  -0.0445 -0.097   0.2378 -0.2111  0.0477  0.1635
  -0.0334 -0.2452  0.0758 -0.025   0.3049 -0.0506 -0.1751  0.013   0.0952
   0.1412 -0.1826 -0.1486  0.3592 -0.2809 -0.0487 -0.146  -0.3831 -0.1877
   0.1693 -0.2139 -0.1026]
 [ 0.1029  0.2837 -0.0368  0.2542  0.2203  0.0769  0.0314  0.2135 -0.2866
   0.2129  0.1155  0.1172 -0.2234  0.1462  0.2613  0.0106 -0.1252  0.3011
   0.1011 -0.1826 -0.2818  0.1572 -0.0463 -0.042   0.1197  0.1352  0.1017
   0.1287  0.068   0.3545]
 [ 0.1091 -0.2829 -0.0153  0.2351 -0.237   0.0461 -0.0413  0.1927 -0.3071
  -0.1768 -0.1019  0.0349  0.2255 -0.2815 -0.0227  0.1133  0.1618  0.2099
  -0.1708 -0.1826 -0.0563 -0.3161 -0.0516 -0.0526 -0.1474 -0.1327  0.1646
   0.0516 -0.3428  0.2167]
 [ 0.1961  0.0576 -0.2106 -0.1627  0.1726 -0.3899 -0.0602 -0.0313  0.1384
  -0.2867 -0.2763  0.2666  0.1716 -0.0577 -0.221  -0.0041 -0.2686  0.3144
   0.1057 -0.1826 -0.0059 -0.0532  0.0054  0.0047 -0.01   -0.1377  0.0715
  -0.048   0.3414  0.0957]
 [ 0.2062 -0.0577 -0.2064 -0.181  -0.167  -0.3523  0.1472 -0.0098  0.2101
   0.2363  0.2289  0.3478 -0.2066  0.1142 -0.013  -0.1398  0.3304  0.1656
  -0.1271 -0.1826 -0.0148  0.0212  0.0189  0.0079  0.0087  0.1718  0.0551
  -0.0572 -0.3294 -0.157 ]
 [ 0.2459  0.0089  0.108  -0.1628  0.005   0.3114 -0.0257 -0.1824  0.0616
   0.0085  0.0007 -0.1875 -0.0141  0.1107 -0.2713 -0.2495 -0.0372 -0.0669
   0.0231 -0.1826  0.094   0.0546  0.1742  0.0162 -0.0115  0.1346  0.3728
  -0.4262 -0.1039  0.3889]
 [-0.2854  0.0787 -0.1811 -0.2771 -0.1645  0.1665 -0.0836  0.1168 -0.0997
  -0.3142  0.1459  0.086  -0.3407 -0.0294  0.0637 -0.0189 -0.0979 -0.0241
   0.379  -0.1826  0.0626 -0.209  -0.066   0.4506  0.0345 -0.0645  0.0675
   0.0152 -0.1238 -0.0312]
 [-0.2847 -0.0959 -0.1681 -0.2758  0.1731  0.1737  0.0601  0.1842 -0.0514
   0.2864 -0.1663  0.0784  0.3341 -0.0492 -0.0238 -0.065   0.078  -0.0501
  -0.3843 -0.1826 -0.1059  0.2063 -0.0645  0.444  -0.0527  0.0571  0.037
   0.049   0.1188  0.042 ]
 [-0.2857 -0.0096 -0.1777 -0.3238  0.0072  0.173  -0.0084  0.2462 -0.1071
  -0.0181 -0.0171  0.0932 -0.0064 -0.1221  0.0723 -0.2336 -0.0391 -0.0619
   0.0052 -0.1826 -0.0055 -0.0225  0.0752 -0.7262  0.0182  0.0167 -0.0614
  -0.104   0.0449 -0.0793]
 [-0.2035  0.1884  0.1326 -0.0372 -0.1982 -0.1819  0.2276 -0.1637 -0.2104
  -0.152  -0.2327 -0.1772 -0.0703  0.1888 -0.1157 -0.1107  0.3868  0.0021
   0.0559 -0.1826  0.1064  0.0754  0.0669 -0.0715 -0.2113  0.1449  0.188
   0.4102  0.2205  0.0589]
 [-0.1944 -0.1764  0.1619 -0.05    0.1931 -0.2218 -0.1924 -0.1343 -0.2023
   0.249   0.2632 -0.0573  0.0481  0.0378 -0.3163  0.0502 -0.3232 -0.0083
   0.0176 -0.1826  0.1504  0.0398  0.0649 -0.0767  0.2001 -0.1511  0.2671
   0.327  -0.2238 -0.1245]
 [-0.2102  0.2198 -0.2078  0.0621 -0.3009  0.1213 -0.2573 -0.2468  0.1993
  -0.2066  0.2381  0.0045  0.0205  0.062  -0.0718  0.462  -0.0528  0.0926
  -0.3346 -0.1826 -0.0638  0.274   0.0274 -0.1203 -0.0199  0.0365 -0.0318
  -0.014   0.0121  0.1095]
 [-0.2038 -0.235  -0.1969  0.0725  0.2863  0.1649  0.2264 -0.1717  0.2828
   0.1899 -0.2226 -0.053   0.0328  0.2512  0.1133  0.3995  0.1516  0.119
   0.2916 -0.1826  0.1515 -0.2236  0.027  -0.1035  0.0199 -0.0456 -0.0063
  -0.0212 -0.1085  0.0979]
 [-0.1956  0.0057  0.233  -0.145   0.0087 -0.2921  0.0224  0.0372 -0.0703
   0.0311  0.0675 -0.4255 -0.0174 -0.0109  0.0025 -0.0568  0.013   0.3534
  -0.0289 -0.1826 -0.0602 -0.0172  0.1678  0.0942  0.0085 -0.0645 -0.54
  -0.2705 -0.1014  0.1564]
 [-0.0571  0.2653 -0.2128  0.3237 -0.0776  0.0139 -0.3599 -0.0058  0.2793
   0.3057  0.0384 -0.2066  0.1763 -0.347   0.0073 -0.31    0.168   0.0851
   0.2598 -0.1826  0.1137 -0.0514  0.0081  0.0458 -0.0534 -0.0304  0.0422
   0.0607  0.0726 -0.0931]
 [-0.0486 -0.2932 -0.1752  0.3345  0.0606  0.0511  0.2851 -0.0523  0.1788
  -0.3107  0.0483 -0.2036 -0.1378  0.0323  0.2188 -0.3847 -0.2863  0.1171
  -0.288  -0.1826  0.1613  0.1154  0.0146  0.0503  0.0767  0.031   0.0478
   0.0957  0.0127 -0.1351]]


E VALUES FOR MATLAB ENG:
[[    0.    ]
 [    3.6565]
 [    4.4332]
 [    7.054 ]
 [    8.1664]
 [   10.4131]
 [   13.2693]
 [   15.9649]
 [   16.9179]
 [   20.8622]
 [   24.7438]
 [   28.2782]
 [   38.9563]
 [   42.4918]
 [   55.1742]
 [   62.0935]
 [   65.703 ]
 [   76.9751]
 [  143.6789]
 [  165.5467]
 [  239.4348]
 [  263.0559]
 [  284.2856]
 [  779.4868]
 [  919.7508]
 [ 1507.522 ]
 [ 1543.3857]
 [ 8389.9546]
 [13716.3716]
 [16543.2911]]

E VALUES FOR NUMPY.EIG:
[16543.2911 13716.3716  8389.9546  1543.3857  1507.522    919.7508
   779.4868   284.2856   263.0559   239.4348   165.5467   143.6789
    76.9751    65.703     62.0935    55.1742    42.4918    38.9563
    28.2782     0.        24.7438    20.8622     3.6565     4.4332
     7.054      8.1664    10.4131    13.2693    16.9179    15.9649]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467026/calculate-eigen-value-in-python-as-same-wayorder-in-matlab

Comment: partially a duplicate, but I am also looking for the same eigenvectors, which doesn't get resolved if I sort the eigenvectors

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the eigen values and vectors you're getting, it seems like you're likely missing something and they're just out of order, but it's hard to tell without having to crank up two programming environments to try your code... help us help you

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the Matlab and NumPy Eigenvalues are the same, but ordered differently. Try to order the NumPy Eigenvalues using e.g. [np.sort()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and see if the Eigenvalues are the same.

Comment: Thank you @NaturalLog, this has resolved the EigenValues Issue. However, my EigenVector values are still incorrect

Comment: @PeadarODonnell are they though? they are ordered in the same way as the eigenvalues, have you compared them correctly? Can you show us that, instead of thousands of random numbers?